# Help Me Understand What is Going On Here? Class/Objects

Tags: objective-c

I'm a beginner and I wrote this code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYPoint : NSObject {

int pointX;
int pointY;

}    

- (void) print;
- (void) setX: (int) x; 
- (void) setY: (int) y; 

@end

@implementation XYPoint

-(void) print {

NSLog(@"X is %i and Y is %i", pointX, pointY);

}

-(void) setX: (int) x {
pointX = x;
}

-(void) setY: (int) y {
pointY = y;
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

XYPoint *myCord = [[XYPoint alloc] init];

[myCord setX: 4];
[myCord setY: 6];

[myCord print];

[myCord release];


[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

What I need help with is I cannot for the life of me understand the relationship between "pointX" and setX and "x"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PointX` is called an *instance variable* - this is what would be called in most other languages a private class-level variable. It represents a piece of information that your class needs to store internally, and by default is not exposed to other objects in the system.

`setX` is a method that you explicitly create, that allows other objects to assign a value to the private `PointX` instance variable. `x` is the parameter that the external calling object passes to the `setX` method.

Note that the most common way of exposing access to a private instance variable is through the use of defined properties. In your case, you would add something like this in your interface:

```
@property (nonatomic) int PointX;
```

and then this in your implementation:

```
@synthesize PointX;
```

This syntax allows you to (effectively) directly access the `PointX` instance variable, by automagically creating a wrapper property (with matching -get and -set methods) with the same name.

Comment: `pointX` in the OP's code is an instance variable, and as such shouldn't be capitalized, nor should the corresponding property. None of the instance variables in the OP's code are private, they're protected (though I doubt that's relevant to the OP's question).

Comment: "This syntax allows you to (effectively) directly access the PointX instance variable, by automagically creating a wrapper property...." You can do that without the property. Using property accessors still involves method invocation, not direct access. Note that the accessors may be doing synchronization, memory management, and key-value observing (KVO) stuff behind the scenes, so there's potentially a huge difference between that and directly accessing the instance variable.

Comment: @jlehr: `PointX` was a typo on my part (but repeated 5 times). Your comments are correct - perhaps you should have answered this question. :)